# How to remove UnderlineSpan() text using button click

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying things out by creating a small notepad project. And now i am having a hard time finding a solution to remove the underline on text. I can set it but i cant remove it.

Heres my code:

### Heres how i set it

#### I use span to get the selected text

```
selectedString.setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

### Heres how i am trying to unset it

```
selectedString.setSpan(UnderlineSpan().updateDrawState(TextPaint().apply { isUnderlineText = false }), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

I tried to search for a solution but no luck can someone help me? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all styling of the `text`, you could just use `toString()` on the `spannable` and it would remove everything.

If you just want to remove the styling of a part of the `spannable`, just make an `anonymous object` of `UnderlineSpan` and `override` its `updateDrawState` method

```
val underlineRemoveSpan = object : UnderlineSpan() {
    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
        ds.isUnderlineText = false
    }
}

selectedString.setSpan(underlineRemoveSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

---

```
selectedString.setSpan(UnderlineSpan().updateDrawState(TextPaint().apply { isUnderlineText = false }), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

This isn't working because, on calling `updateDrawState` with a new `TextPaint` after setting `isUnderlineText` to `false`. The implementation of `updateDrawState` in `UnderlineSpan` class, sets it to `true`, which is why underline is not removing.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a class like this

```kotlin
class NoUnderlineSpan : UnderlineSpan() {
    override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
        ds.color = ds.linkColor
        ds.isUnderlineText = false
    }
}
```

Then use NoUnderlineSpan just like you use UnderlineSpan

Or you can try this lib I wrote ：[SpannableStringDslExtension](https://github.com/junerver/SpannableStringDslExtension)